# What can make a person who was not born mute go mute over a single night?

Tags: science-based, anatomy

My character is a person who was not born mute. He could talk until the age of 26 until something happens and he loses his ability to talk itself. Can anything like an accident cause permanent muteness to people?

Comment: Car accident, gone mute, like comatose? Can you be more specific.

Comment: Four negative votes and three votes to close for a question that can be (and has been) answered satisfactorially seems very harsh. Not every question needs to be exceedingly verbose and full of (unnecesary) detail, nor need overcomplicated answers to be a good question on this site. Or at least, that used to be the case...

Comment: @Rekesoft the close votes don't call for more details. So your critique fails there.

Comment: @VLAZ pedantry, the true essence of stack exchange

Comment: It's a pure medical question, no Worldbuilding context. If you wish to put a discussion point that that's not the way things should be, then consider adding to this [meta post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10334/were-going-to-upgrade-the-help-center-page-here-is-the-100-000-foot-view-discu). @Rekesoft

Comment: @MS when somebody spends most of the comment to rant about close voters wanting useless details and none of the close votes are for that - that's not pedantry. I'm not obsessing over minor details here, the entire comment is based on what the commenter imagined. I'd appreciate not trying to claim that's not the case. Thanks.

Comment: @Rekesoft This is the fundamental problem of the Real World Question policy when not involving a specific worldbuilding context. The OP is asking for help telling their story, which we specifically prohibit in the [help/on-topic]. The fact that there are satisfactory answers is irrelevant. (The fact that one of them was given by a moderator is, but that's a different discussion.) Without an explanation for why the OP's world is different from Earth that requires the Real World question to be answered because normal research is no longer valid, it's just storybuilding.

Comment: @JBH We have dozens of questions asking about what kind of poisons could provoke certain conditions, how could you kill someone using some esoteric method or what effect could have removing/adding/modifying some organ/limb/hormone in the body. These are all purely medical questions, and they have all been accepted. We have also many "purely chemistry", "purely physics" or "purely astronomy". Do you want me to dig examples? There are tons of them: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/164079/a-hard-to-detect-slow-acting-poison-that-can-be-an-antidote-to-another-poison

Comment: @Rekesoft The Real World Question debate went on for years. Your profile says you've been a site member for 7 years, but your first interaction was July 2021. Thus, you've been a member long enough to have been part of that debate... but your interaction history suggests you weren't. Yes, we've historically answered a lot of questions that are better suited for other stacks. That doesn't mean anything. Policies change. We'll be addressing this one as part of the larger [help center upgrade](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10334/40609) process. And I'm not a fan of Qs like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A lesion in [Broca's area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broca%27s_area)**

In fact, that place in the brain was discovered by autopsy of several patients who had sudden breakage of speech over the course of their lives. Be warned however, such lesions are normally irreparable, thus if you want your patient to "miraculously heal" or just recover, check other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Anything that severely damages the organs involved in producing the voice will surely cause a person go mute overnight.

For examples in the past a punishment for those who had offended an authority with their speech was to cut their tongue away. Alai's Red Poppies contains such an example.

In the same way a trauma to the vocal cords can make it impossible to produce sounds, resulting again in mutism. People who are intubated or get a tracheotomy cannot talk for a while. Imagine something like that, but not reversible.